# What is the Watch Level setting do in RadPHP?

Tags: settings, radphp

In RadPHP version XE2 go to menu item ***Tools|Options|PHP|Internal Webserver***.

There you will see a setting for "**Watch Level**" What is this for?

The help has a information on the Internal Webserver settings but it does not say anything about **Watch Level** and I can't find any information on what it could be for.

Does anyone know?